# Need help setting the same values for radiobutton list in gridview in ItemTemplate based on selected value radiobuttion list in HeaderTemplate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

i've been tasked to create a Gridview in which a user click a radiobutton list on the header **(rblDifficulty)** and all the radiobutton list in the rows below **(rblDiff)** will be set to the same values. I've looked and modify examples using checkboxes and jquery but without success.  Hope someone can guide me on this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data" DataKeyNames="ID"  AllowPaging="true" PageSize ="15"
        class="" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                                  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Difficulty">
              <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rblDifficulty"  runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Easy" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Hard" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
              </asp:RadioButtonList>
              </HeaderTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDiff" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Easy" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Hard" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

UPDATE:  jomsk1e helped me on this

```
 Protected Sub rblDifficulty_onChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim rblDifficulty As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(gvData.HeaderRow.FindControl("rblDifficulty"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim selectedValue__1 As String = rblDifficulty.SelectedValue

    For Each row In gvData.Rows
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("rblDiff"), RadioButtonList)
        rbl.SelectedValue = selectedValue__1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So if you are selecting in header "Easy" , all the items in Gridview-column should be made Easy ? Is that your need ?

Comment: yes, that is what i need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using server side processing:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rblDifficulty"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblDifficulty_onChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Easy" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Hard" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

protected void rblDifficulty_onChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList rblDifficulty = (RadioButtonList)gvData.HeaderRow.FindControl("rblDifficulty");
    string selectedValue = rblDifficulty.SelectedValue;

    foreach (gvData row in gvData.Rows)
    {
        RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rblDiff");
        rbl.SelectedValue = selectedvalue;
    }
}
```

Not tested, but will definitely give you a hint how to do it. Good luck! :)

Comment: tq i have it working now:                                                                Protected Sub rblDifficulty_onChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim rblDifficulty As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(gvData.HeaderRow.FindControl("rblDifficulty"), RadioButtonList)
        Dim selectedValue__1 As String = rblDifficulty.SelectedValue

        For Each row In gvData.Rows
            Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("rblDiff"), RadioButtonList)
            rbl.SelectedValue = selectedValue__1
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: You can edit your post and show your solution to your problem. And please add VB as tags to your post. It may be a good help for others later on.